# Can we bind from code behind for combobox WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

I fellow a solution for binding data to combobox from code behind, but I get the content of the first element is dispatched in the combobox list like this: 
s 
t 
a 
c 
k 
How can I solve this?

**XAML**:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="value1"/>
```

**C#**

```
value1.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("myClass") { Source = getListOfObjectsOfmyClass(), Path = new PropertyPath("attributeInmyClass") });
```

```
class myClass{
   public int id {get; set;}
   public string attributeInmyClass {get; set;}
}
```

**Modified:**

```
public List<myClass> getListOfObjectsOfmyClass(){
   ...
  return listOfObjectMyClass;
}
```

Comment: you should rather use simple `new Binding() { Source = getListOfObjectsOfmyClass() }` and set `DisplayMemberPath` (or override ToString of myClass) ... **also why using binding then** ... it doesn't make sens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution propsed by @Selvin:

```
value1.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding() { Source = getListOfObjectsOfmyClass() });
value1.DisplayPathMember = "attributeInmyClass ";
```